# How to add to add a parameter with multiple values using retrofit? including @Field and @Query

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

this is the url I want to add:

> /survey/add?moderator_id=1&password=123456&visitor_name=nabil&visitor_mobile=123456&entity_id=32&visitor_gender=male&survey={"opinion":"great event","answers":[{"answer":1,"question_id":9},{"answer":1,"question_id":10},{"answer":1,"question_id":11}]}

i want to add the last parameter to the my post request, how to do that!

this is the post request:

```
public interface Serviecs {
    @POST("survey/{add}")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<SubmitSurvey> getSubmit(@Path("add") String add,
                                 @Field("moderator_id") int moderator_id,
                                 @Field("visitor_name") String visitor_name,
                                 @Field("visitor_mobile") String visitor_mobile,
                                 @Field("entity_id") int entity_id,
                                 @Field("visitor_gender") String visitor_gender
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Call<SubmitSurvey> getSubmit(@Path("add") String add,
                             @Field("moderator_id") int moderator_id,
                             @Field("visitor_name") String visitor_name,
                             @Field("visitor_mobile") String visitor_mobile,
                             @Field("entity_id") int entity_id,
                             @Query ReqAnsQues visitor_gender
);
```

And the structure of ReqAnsQues

```
Class ReqAnsQues{
     @SerializedName("answer")
     String answer;
     @SerializedName("visitor_gender")
     String visitorGender; 
}
```

*@Field requires a mandatory parameter. In cases when @Field is optional, we can use @Query instead and pass a null value*

Comment: thank you for helping, but the problem is i want to add the parameter survey

Comment: where you want to add parameter survey, please share more details

Comment: i want to add it as a @Field to complete the url to make a post request

Comment: i have to class SubmitSurvey and SubmitAnswers , the user will answer the survey questions and it will sent to the server

Comment: if you found the solution please upvote and mark as answer.